# How to embed mermaid graphs in quarto documents used to generate gitlab wiki pages

Tags: markdown, quarto, mermaid

The workflow I'm aiming for is to generate gitlab wiki pages from Quarto including mermaid diagrams.

**Issue** : Somehow, when quarto produces the .md file, it replaces `>` symbols with `&gt;`, which breaks the mermaid rendering in Gitlab.

**Reproducible code**:

- The quarto file :

  ````
  ---
  title: "test gfm mermaid"
  format:
     gfm
  ---

  Text

  ```{mermaid}
  flowchart LR
     A-->B
  ```
  ````
- The resulting markdown file (obtained with `quarto render test-gfm-mermaid.qmd`) :

  ````
  # test gfm mermaid

  Text

  ``` mermaid
  flowchart LR
     A--&gt;B
  ```
  ````

**Expected outcome**: I guess maintaining the integrity of mermaid snippets.

**Versions** :

```
[✓] Checking versions of quarto binary dependencies...
      Pandoc version 3.1.1: OK
      Dart Sass version 1.55.0: OK
[✓] Checking versions of quarto dependencies......OK
[✓] Checking Quarto installation......OK
      Version: 1.3.450
      Path: /opt/quarto/bin

[✓] Checking basic markdown render....OK
```

Comment: Of course I can solve my issue using `sed -i 's/&gt;/>/' test-gfm-mermaid.md`, but that's not the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is [an issue with quarto version 1.3](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/5319), which is [resolved in quarto version 1.4](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/pull/5426). So I think you are using a Quarto version below 1.4. Upgrade to version 1.4 and try again.

With quarto `v1.4.547`, `quarto render test-gfm-mermaid.qmd` generates,

````
# test gfm mermaid


Text

``` mermaid
flowchart LR
   A-->B
```
````

---

Also if you are an mermaid user, I would recommend to keep an eye on [this Github issue thread](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/5416).